# QMediaPlayer shows green-screen video

Tags: qt

I'm trying to run a video with QMediaPlayer & QVideoWidget,
everything is okay but the video is only shows a green screen.
I have tried another videos and still the same issue.

my code:

```
    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("E:\\gd.mp4"));
    vw = new QVideoWidget;
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::errorChanged, this, &Widget::catchError);
    connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::durationChanged, this, &Widget::getDuration);
    vw->show();
    player->play();
```

Comment: Recommendation: Back up your current code and hack it down to a [mre] (MRE). If making the MRE doesn't help you find and fix the mistake, and it usually does, you're in a much better position to ask a tightly focused question about the MRE.

Comment: what OS and what media system you're using if that's not Windows? Are you able to playback that mp4 in other players on same system? THe message means that codec met some issues.

Comment: i'm using windows, I do not know what do you mean by *media system*, yes i'm able to play this video on Windows media player, it was work on Qt 6.4.2, since i upgraded it to 6.5 this problem appeared

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Qt 6.5.0 moved to the ffmpeg backend. Try to set the env variable QT_MEDIA_BACKEND to "windows" as reported [in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-index.html#target-platform-and-backend-notes) to use the previous backend.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: Simplest way is to add this line as the first instruction of your application, inside main: qputenv("QT_MEDIA_BACKEND", "windows");. First instruction of your main function.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-building.html or use the online installer

Comment: i'm using QMake to build the project also i have downloaded the Mingw and  Msvc2019 from MaintenanceTool, but when i make a new Project i can't use the Msvc2019 (It is visible, but it has a yellow exclamation mark, and can't mark the box and use it), I only need to use QWebengine and it require the compiler to be set as Msvc2019, if you know a solution with Mingw it would be nice

Comment: Afaik no solution. Chromium does not support mingw. If you need webengine you can only use msvc on windows. That is a known limitation, unless something changed recently.